# Change Login Table in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two table one is "clUser" in which i am storing email id,
another table name "clLogin" in which i am storing Password.
How to change laravel default login with these two table.

Comment: At first, why do you need to separate the two table?

Comment: @MuhammadHabib Thank you for you reply i don't need 2 seprate table but i want to use laravel with my existing old database and i have that kind of structure if you help me it would be great